# Firebase Storage read security rules don't seem to be having any effect

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm working to set my security rules for my Firebase Storage and the read rules do not seem to be having any effect whatsoever.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;

    }
  }
}
```

I can take any imgURL that I have stored and paste it into my browser, and it pulls the image right up.  I logged out of the firebase account and also out of Xcode thinking that maybe

Even if I remove the 'read' from the code above and only specify the write permission, it still allows a read if I paste an URL from one of the files into my browser.

It's like my folder is set to an open read or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `imgURL` you are talking about is a so-called **download URL**, then this is the expected behavior. Firebase's download URLs provide public, read-only access to the file, bypassing the security rules.

If you want to only allow secured access to the data, you should not generate a download URL and only access the file through the other SDK [download methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files).